# mat-chip-grid must be used in combination with matChipInputFor

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am getting this error while running angular test cases in angular15 version, can anyone help me to resolve this error.

This is my code

```html
<mat-chip-grid>
    <mat-chip-row highlighted *ngFor="let color of colors">
        {{color.name}}
    </mat-chip-row>
</mat-chip-grid>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an input with the `matChipInputFor` directive in conjunction with `mat-chip-grid`.

If your code doesn't require interactive logic and is more about visual elements, consider using `mat-chip-set` **instead of** `mat-chip-grid`